# Same hash in django and php(bb) forum

Tags: database, django, hash, passwords, phpbb3

I'm trying to integrate phpbb3 into my django website. The problem I have is that I use django.auth for main site authentication. But I want phpbb and django to share the same database or maintain some synchronization between them.

One of the problems is that if I want to update the phpbb database from django I need to hash the password in the same format as phpbb reads them .. but I'm not sure on how to do this? Im no hash/encryption pro...

Any tips on this? Or do you have another idea of how I can design the system?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not along with this task, try look here http://code.google.com/p/django-phpbb/
This is not 100% ready solution, but you can check some code where, also here is some article http://www.gilesthomas.com/?p=63

Answer (score 2):

phpBB3 uses [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for its password hashing. The phpass page also lists a python port called [python-phpass](https://github.com/exavolt/python-phpass).

Because phpBB3 changes the hash identifier from '$P$' to '$H$', you will have to replace this line:

```
outp = '$P$'
```

with this one:

```
outp = '$H$'
```